# How to get two inputs from two different input-views?

Tags: bixby, inputview

I am developing a Bixby capsule and I found a problem that I cannot overcome.

I have an action that returns some data based on the weather and user preferences.
My concept are **Weather** and **Preferences**.

I've already got data about the weather which are displayed in result-view. Now (in weather input-view) I choose one day to have weather information only about that one day. Next I go to preferences input-view and this is where the problem starts. As soon as I click on submit button, weather information is not remembered anymore and it redirects me again to weather input-view (where I chose one day earlier). The problem is that all weather information, that I had, already disappeared so I cannot choose anything.

I need weather information and preferences and all I get is preferences and no possibility to get weather information as it gets lost in the meantime.

Does anyone know how to make it work?
I will really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code and how your modeling is done, I can only say that multiple inputs can be requested from the user via `input-view` as you described.

For more targeted assistance, please reach out to the Bixby Developer Support team via Bixby Studio's "Contact Support" option in the Help menu.